# How to calculate the probability Y is > a specified value from a fitted regression model?

Tags: regression, probability, self-study

> Suppose that in the population, the annual salary (`Salary`) of CEOs, measured in millions of dollars, is related to the annual sales of the company (`Sales`) measured in millions of dollars according to the following
>
> regression model: Salary = 5 + 0.1*Sales + residual
> residuals are iid and independent of sales
> residual ~ N(0.9^(2)), and sales~ N(50,10)

What is the probability the salary of a CEO is greater than 7 million dollars if the value for sales is 10 million dollars? How do I calculate this? I have no idea about how to do it. Does it relate to the t-table?  (numerical answer is 0.4562)

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "(numerical answer is 0.4562)"? Was that given to you as the answer? When you write, "N(0.9^(2))", should that be 'N(***0,*** 0.9^(2))'? How many data were use to fit the model (ie, what is the residual degrees of freedom)?

Comment: If the model is known with certainty then, conditional on $X=x$, $Y$ is distributed as $N(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x, .9^2)$. In this problem, you know $\beta_0 = 5$ $\beta_1 = 0.1$, $x = 10$, and $y = 7$. Plug in the values and you just have a regular normal distribution calculation....  Another hint: $$ P(Y > y) = P \left( Z > \frac{y - (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}{.9} \right ) $$

Comment: Hint: Given the answer (which is off in the last significant digit, attributable to only retaining 2 significant digits on the input value), the residual must be N(0,9^2), not N(0,.9^2), i.e., the question posting has a  typo of "." instead of ",".  P.S. The CEOs are overpaid.